# IBM Db2 on Cloud (lite plan): Change user role in Service credentials

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I would like to use the lite version of Db2 on Cloud on IBM Cloud for my application. I created Db2, but I can only select the manager role in service credentials. This prevents me from creating a schema or a table using a PyCharm connection through the ibm_db module.
I've got the error:

> ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError: ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0551N  The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation.  Authorization ID: "******".  Operation: "CREATE TABLE". Object: "schema_name.table_name".  SQLSTATE=42501\r SQLCODE=-551

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is addressed in the [FAQ for Db2 on Cloud lite plan](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-faq_db2oc_lite#fp_faq_schema). Because it is a shared database environment, you don't have any administration privileges. Hence it is not possible to create a schema.

You can create new tables which are in your assigned schema. Leave out the schema name in the two part name, e.g., use `CREATE TABLE mytable` instead of `CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable`.